# Python: Pulling data out of dictionary like a 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have a python dictionary where all values are arrays of the same length. I would like to be able to pull out, by element number, these values.

I have a dictionary like this:

```
dictionary = { 'key1': [1,2,3], 'key2': [4,5,6], 'key3': [7,8,9] }
```

And I would like this output when calling the argument 1:

```
[2,5,8]
```

The best I have is

```
[dictionary.values()[0][1], dictionary.values()[1][1], dictionary.values()[2][1] ]
```

because

```
dictioinary.values()[:][1]
```

does not work even though dictionary.values() returns a list.

Or would it be easier to store this data in a 2D array or use numpy? I would like to use a dictionary so I can call data by the key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using plain Python, you could use a list comprehension:

```
In [106]: [dictionary[key][1] for key in ('key1', 'key2', 'key3')]
Out[106]: [2, 5, 8]
```

(Since `dict` keys are unordered, if you want to access the values corresponding to 'key1', 'key2', 'key3' in that order, you have to state the keys explicitly, or use something like `sorted(dictionary.keys())`).

---

Climbing up the ladder of convenience, you could instead use NumPy. The following converts the dictionary to an array:

```
In [111]: arr = np.array([dictionary[key] for key in ('key1', 'key2', 'key3')]).T

In [112]: arr
Out[112]: 
array([[1, 4, 7],
       [2, 5, 8],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```

To select the second row of the array:

```
In [113]: arr[1]
Out[113]: array([2, 5, 8])
```

and to select the second column:

```
In [120]: arr[:, 1]
Out[120]: array([4, 5, 6])
```

If you want to refer to the columns by the key name, then you could define a keymap:

```
In [126]: keymap = dict(zip(('key1', 'key2', 'key3'), range(3)))

In [127]: keymap
Out[127]: {'key1': 0, 'key2': 1, 'key3': 2}

In [128]: arr[:, keymap['key2']]
Out[128]: array([4, 5, 6])
```

---

Even higher up the ladder of convenience, there is [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/):
Pandas DataFrames support accessing data based on column and/or index (row) labels:

```
In [129]: import pandas as pd

In [130]: df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)

In [131]: df
Out[131]: 
   key1  key2  key3
0     1     4     7
1     2     5     8
2     3     6     9

In [132]: df['key2']
Out[132]: 
0    4
1    5
2    6
Name: key2, dtype: int64

In [133]: df.iloc[1]  # Get the second row of the DataFrame
Out[133]: 
key1    2
key2    5
key3    8
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

```
p = lambda index: [val[index] for val in dictionary.values()]
p(0) #will give 0th index of the array
```

Answer (score 0):

numpy is a good choice if you are familiarized with Matlab and you need to make operations over rows and columns

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> matrix = np.matrix('1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9')
>>> matrix[:,2]
matrix([[3],
        [6],
        [9]])
>>> matrix[:,1]
matrix([[2],
        [5],
        [8]])
```

But you can create an 2D array and implement your own function to extract a column

```
m = [[1,2,3],
     [4,5,6],
     [7,8,9]]

def column(matrix, i):
    return [row[i] for row in matrix]
```

in your terminal

```
>>> column(m, 1)
[2, 5, 8]
```

Or use the  comprehension directly

```
[row[1] for row in m]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map and itemgetter.

please [check here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) what map does

`from operator import itemgetter
dictionary = { 'key1': [1,2,3], 'key2': [4,5,6], 'key3': [7,8,9] }
map(itemgetter(1), dictionary.values())`

however that will return an unordered list since values iterates the dictionary.

you can try to do a reverse on the result. I am not sure if it's a good idea to use OrderedDict form collection package also

I don't see any point on using numpy for solving this. do I am missing something?